# How to debug this simple socket client-server application?

Tags: java, swing, sockets, jframe, client-server

I make a menu like simple socket program. But after I successfully send and print one menu, the console print "null" and, I can't send or print any menu anymore and console print "Connection refused: connect"

Like this

4 input, one success print and a null, another 3 looks like below.

> null
>
> Connection refused: connect
>
> Connection refused: connect
>
> Connection refused: connect

I'm still a newbie indeed, and I use jframe which is I rarely see in Stack Overflow.

Server.java

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.concurrent.Delayed;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import static javax.swing.JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE;

/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
/**
 *
 * @author Dicko
 */
public class Server extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public static int PORT = 1111;
    public static int PORT2 = 1996;
    public static DataInputStream DIS;

    static String bon = "";
    static String harga = "";

    /**
     * Creates new form Server
     */
    public Server() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        btn_ok = new javax.swing.JButton();
        lbl_total = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txa_bon = new javax.swing.JTextArea();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Server");

        btn_ok.setText("OK");
        btn_ok.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btn_okActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        lbl_total.setText("0");

        jLabel2.setText("Rp");

        txa_bon.setColumns(20);
        txa_bon.setRows(5);
        txa_bon.setEditable(false);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(txa_bon);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(0, 182, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jLabel2)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(lbl_total, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 71, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addComponent(btn_ok))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 255, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btn_ok)
                    .addComponent(lbl_total)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        setBounds(500, 150, 377, 345);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btn_okActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                      

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Server.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Server().setVisible(true);
                Client cl = new Client();
                cl.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
        try {
            ServerSocket SS = new ServerSocket(PORT);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Koneksi Terhubung", "Server Info", INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            Socket clientSocket = SS.accept();
            DIS = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            String tmp = "";

            while (!tmp.equals("stop")) {
                tmp = DIS.readUTF();
                bon = tmp;
                txa_bon.append(bon);
            }
            DIS.close();
            SS.close();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btn_ok;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lbl_total;
    private static javax.swing.JTextArea txa_bon;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Client.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.net.Socket;

/**
 *
 * @author Dicko
 */
public class Client extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public static int Port = 1111;
    public static int Port2 = 1996;
    public static String IP = "localhost";
    public static PrintStream cetak;

    /**
     * Creates new form Client
     */
    public Client() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        btn_nasi = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btn_bakso = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btn_mie = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Client");
        setResizable(false);

        btn_nasi.setText("Nasi");
        btn_nasi.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btn_nasiActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btn_bakso.setText("Bakso");
        btn_bakso.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btn_baksoActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btn_mie.setText("Mie Ayam");
        btn_mie.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btn_mieActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(btn_nasi)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(btn_mie)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(btn_bakso)
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(btn_nasi)
                    .addComponent(btn_bakso)
                    .addComponent(btn_mie))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        setBounds(150, 150, 265, 84);
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btn_nasiActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String str = "Nasi Rp 2.000 ,-";
        try {
            Socket cs = new Socket(IP, Port);
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());
            dout.writeUTF(str);
            dout.flush();
            dout.close();
            cs.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    }                                        

    private void btn_mieActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
        String str = "Mie Ayam Rp 4.000 ,-";
        try {
            Socket cs = new Socket(IP, Port);
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());
            dout.writeUTF(str);
            dout.flush();
            dout.close();
            cs.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }                                       

    private void btn_baksoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
        String str = "Bakso Rp 5.000 ,-";
        try {
            Socket cs = new Socket(IP, Port);
            DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());
            dout.writeUTF(str);
            dout.flush();
            dout.close();
            cs.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }                                         

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Client().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton btn_bakso;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn_mie;
    private javax.swing.JButton btn_nasi;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Close up Server.java

```
try {
        ServerSocket SS = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Koneksi Terhubung", "Server Info", INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        Socket clientSocket = SS.accept();
        DIS = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
        String tmp = "";

        while (!tmp.equals("stop")) {
            tmp = DIS.readUTF();
            bon = tmp;
            txa_bon.append(bon);
        }
        DIS.close();
        SS.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```

Close up Client.java

```
String str = "Nasi Rp 2.000 ,-";
    try {
        Socket cs = new Socket(IP, Port);
        DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(cs.getOutputStream());
        dout.writeUTF(str);
        dout.flush();
        dout.close();
        cs.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Comment: Try using `this.IP` and `this.Port` i.e. `new Socket(this.IP, this.Port)`! Also see this for the error message you are getting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4959760/java-networking-connection-refused-connect

Comment: you have an issue with EDT, there is a few attampts in MCVE / SSCCE form, search for Swing + SwingWorker + Socket,